# Logic behind SQL query code to fetch data?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, left-join

I'm interested in knowing how this query works if i want to execute in my SQL Developer to check whether it fetches the correct data.

When i started debugging our java code, i ended up finding the query which look for data in table however it is confusing me the way it has been handled. Can anyone explain me the logic ? Also can anyone show me what would be my SQL query if i want to execute in Database Client ?

```
select distinct pA.id
 from CHECK_TABLE pA 
 left join pA.node node
 left join pA.kms km
 where 1=1
```

POJO's

```
public class CHECK_TABLE implements XXXDataObject
{
    private long                     id                   = 0;
    private String                   name                 = null;
    private XXNode                   node                 = null;
    private List<Akm>                kms                  = null;


    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId( long id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    .....
    .....

    public XXNode getNode()
    {
        return node;
    }


    public void setNode( XXNode node )
    {
        this.node = node;
    }

    @ManyToMany( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, targetEntity = com.XXXXXXXXXX.Akm.class )
    @JoinTable( name = "TABLE_KM", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "TABLE_ID" ) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "KM_ID" ) } )
    public List<Akm> getKms()
    {
        return kms;
    }

    public void setKms( List<Akm> kms )
    {
        this.kms = kms;
    }

}
```

I see corresponding tables in my database for CHECK_TABLE,  XXNode, Akm. However CHECK_TABLE holds data except XXNode, Akm which are connected by foreign key constraint.

Comment: *"in JAVA"*  There is no need to add the major tag in the title.  Also no need to SHOUT at us (it is 'Java').

Answer (score 0):

The query could be reduced to

```
select distinct pA.id from CHECK_TABLE pA
```

and it translates to the following SQL query:

```
select distinct pA.id from CHECK_TABLE pA
```

To know how a HQL query translates to SQL, simply enable SQL logging in Hibernate, and see what Hibernate logs. This can be done by setting the [hibernate.show_sql property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-properties) to true in the configuration file.